# how to added onKeyPress on empty dhtmlxgrid?

Tags: dhtmlx

`onKeyPress()` event work fine when Grid has row in `DhtmlxGrid`. But when Grid is empty, event is not getting fire.
 My code is :

```
grd.attachEvent("onKeyPress", ongrdInsert);
function ongrdInsert(nKeyCode,Ctrl,Shift,Event)
{                                                                                   
    if (40 == nKeyCode)
    {
         alert("ongrdInsert");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is confirmed and fixed. If you have active support subscription, you may open a ticket at support.dhtmlx.com to get the fix. Also it will be included in the next dhtmlxGrid release.